# How to convert srcElement into string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclicklistener, tostring, getelementsbyclassname

I am using a for loop to add a onClick listener to my textboxes and when the user clicks the textbox it gets its ID.

What I want to do is convert the ID that I am getting into a string because there are some task that require me to use string and not ID.

```
var textbox = getElementsByClassName("myTextbox");
var textboxID = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < textbox.length; i++) {

        textbox[i].addEventListener("click", function(listener) {
             textboxID = listener.srcElement;
            });
}
```

I have tried: `textboxID = listener.srcElement.toString();` and `textboxID.toString()` but had no luck.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: is it not String already? What exactly are you getting in srcElement now? Please mention.

Comment: Hi, javascript doesn't recognise it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id property of the object that srcElement refers to:

```
textboxID = listener.srcElement.id;
```

Comment: I am trying to :) but it says I have to wait 3 more mins